Target encoding in linear regression
I have a dataset with the loss rates of each contract as dependent variable. As independent variables I have country (four values), profession (5 values) and income (continous variable). I apply binning and create for each independent variable a few monotonic buckets. After I apply target encoding by using the mean loss rate of each bucket as independent variable in regression.
After, I run the multivariate linear regression. If, e.g., contract 1 originates from countries in bucket 1, proffesions from bucket 1, and income category from bucket 2, it means:
loss rate of contract 1 = alpha + beta1mean loss rate of all countries in bucket 1 + beta2mean loss rate of all contracts with professions in bucket 2 + beta3*mean loss rate all contracts withih income bucket 2.
How can I interpret the coefficients and results of the regression? Do I have some bias because the mean loss rate of the bucket depends on the loss rate of each particular contract from this bucket?

Why are you binning and exactly how are you doing that?

I apply binning to catch the possible non-linear relation. I group the contracts based on mean loss rate (e.g., countries 1, 2, and 6 have a similar mean loss rate, that means that all contracts from these countries will be in one bucket; countries 3, 7, have a higher mean loss rate, these will be in second bucket, ...). The problem for me is that I am not sure if it makes much sense to predict the loss rate of a particular contract with the mean loss rate of the bucket where it originates from

That's not a good method to catch nonlinearity. Much better to use a spline.
